# Free clothing design program

Tags: gratis, visual-design

I need a free (preferably [open source](https://opensource.com/resources/what-open-source)) clothing design program.

What I found:

- For example, the section "Creating a garment with Optitex and Blender: Constructing a Boudicca dress" (of Thomas Makryniotis. 2015. [*3D Fashion Design: Technique, Design and Visualization*](https://opensource.com/resources/what-open-source). Pavilion Books.) mentions [**Blender**](https://www.blender.org/), which is a free open source 3D modeling program.

  cf. my related Blender Stack Exchange question: [*Can Blender be used to design 2D clothing patterns?*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/69557/15464)
- [**Inkscape**](https://inkscape.org/) is the best free open source 2D design program, but it is not specifically intended for creating clothing patterns, although one could certainly use it for that purpose.